# merge unallocated partition

Tags: partitioning, disk

I am unable to merge my unallocated partition to my `/dev/sda1`.

I tried `gparted` etc. but no success so far. I need you help to extend my `/dev/sda1` disk size using my unallocated space. Please suggest.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It looks like your image didn't show up; if you intended to include a screenshot, please edit your post to include it. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize partitions?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Chandra. You cannot merge the unallocated space to partitions unless it is right next to the partition.

Comment: this helped me merging two spaces. because there was a middle unused block. I deleted it and was able to merge both of them

Answer (score 0):

Simply you cannot alter the partition on which the current OS is running.

The solution is to make a bootable DVD or USB and boot your system with it. then you can alter the partition (sda1).

Yet, you should be careful about one thing: most probably the UUID of sda1 will get changed after alteration. Therefore, you should update you fstab and grub for the new UUID.

Answer (score -1):

I think the simple solution is, back up all your data on the current partition, delete them all, recreate new one.